# AngularJS change location

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to call a route with parameters by myself.

I found the $location.search - function that could be used, but it doesn't work with my configuration:

```
$location.search('/students', {id:id});
$location.path('/students').search({id:id});
```

Both don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your route is defined as:

```
'/students/:id'
```

Then you would need to set your location path by:

```
$location.path('/students/' + id);
```